# How do I pass certificate common name to istio internal service in istio 1.4.0?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I followed the setup in below link to enable secure connection to ingress gateway

```
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress-sds/
```

I can send request and get the response from internal service, but is there a way to access certificate common name in internal service?

Internal service is running the following flask application.

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/first")
def index():
    return str(request.headers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

And it is giving the following output

```
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: 10.32.0.5
X-Envoy-Decorator-Operation: flasksvc.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/first
X-Request-Id: f5f4d99f-0fe6-450b-a836-f4f228a5908d
X-B3-Traceid: a057039d68a629d516a7e36660197be8
X-Istio-Attributes: Ck8KCnNvdXJjZS51a....
Host: flaskapp.example.com
X-B3-Spanid: 16a7e36660197be8
X-Envoy-Internal: true
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Content-Length: 0
X-B3-Sampled: 0
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

I want to see certificate common name in response, could you please help me how to do it with istio 1.4.0 version

Comment: So if I understood correctly You want to add custom header that has common name from Your certificate?

Comment: yes, I want to see certificate common name in above response

Comment: client certificate common name will be different for each request

Answer (score 2):

Well what you need to do is configure istio ingress gateway to perform SNI passthrough without terminating the TLS. Check this [guide](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/) on how to do it.

Comment: I am getting connection refused after enabling passthrugh, and also is it mandatory to use nginx?

Comment: Nginx is just a sample pod used in this guide...in reality you should replace it with your own pod

Comment: It did not display certificate common name in output

Comment: You only have the pass thought sample deployed in the cluster right or is there TLS termination example as well? check this issue https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11786

Comment: That output..how are you getting it?

Comment: X-Forwarded-Client-Cert: By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default;Hash=f01d1affa44958806225a0316afc3112789256a2084f0ecd1a84d765c0199cf3;Subject="";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account

Comment: I wrote a python flask application to print headers, in above comment, subject is empty

Comment: The above output you were getting this already before or getting it with the  SNI passthrough? Also mutual TLS enabled globally? and You have DestinationRule infront of your app with tls_mode set to istio_mutual

Comment: SNI passthrough is configured at gateway level, this above output is printed in python file which is in application container which will be after gateway only. I configured mutual TLS globally and destination rule is also configured.

When I send request to ingress gateway, it is calling my application with ingress service account it seems.

Comment: I am still getting empty subject even after trying in different ways, could you please check the link https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19933 and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This answer is indeed correct solution, @KalyanKumar there might be something wrong with Your deployment of Your application. You can check if the protocol is correct and port is named like in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560394/how-to-terminate-ssl-at-ingress-gateway-in-istio/59578064#59578064).

Comment: It did not work with SNI passthrough, I did not add caCertificates option to gateway, so it caused this issue. Please check my github link github.com/istio/istio/issues/19933