# Istio Egress MTLs for external services

Tags: kubernetes, istio, mtls

I'm currently (and unsuccessfully) trying to setup MTLs via `istio-egressgateway` to access an external K8s cluster service. I'm following the intructions specified on [istio docs](https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#perform-mutual-tls-origination-with-an-egress-gateway) but nothing works as expected, and I'm not able to see where I'm wrong.

**Environment**

- 3 VMs under VMWare ESXi (1 master, 2 Nodes)
- OS : CentOS 7 with kernel `5.2.10-1.el7` from elrepo
- k8s networking : `cilium -1.6.4`
- Certificates : `cert-manager-0.12` nowebhook

  - ClusterIssuer CA cert = Imported from private PKI
- K8s external load balancer : `metallb-0.8.3`

`kubectl` and `istio` used in K8s cluster

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:23:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.4", GitCommit:"224be7bdce5a9dd0c2fd0d46b83865648e2fe0ba", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-11T12:37:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ istioctl version
client version: 1.2.10
citadel version: 1.2.10
egressgateway version: 1.2.10
galley version: 1.2.10
ingressgateway version: 1.2.10
pilot version: 1.2.10
policy version: 1.2.10
sidecar-injector version: 1.2.10
telemetry version: 1.2.10
```

**`istio-egressgateway`** has been redeployed as indicated in [istio docs](https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#redeploy-the-egress-gateway-with-the-client-certificates)

This are the applied `.yaml` is almost a copy-paste from the example, with a minor modification to point to an external service via it's IP address

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: tools-istio
spec:
  hosts:
  - <my.hostname>
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  endpoints:
  - address: <private_ip_address>
    ports:
      https: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: tools-istio
spec:
  hosts:
  - <my.hostname>
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - <my.hostname>
    route:
    - destination:
        host: <my.hostname>
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway
  namespace: tools-istio
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - <my.hostname>
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      serverCertificate: /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/key.pem
      caCertificates: /etc/certs/root-cert.pem
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-for-nginx
  namespace: tools-istio
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: nginx
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
      portLevelSettings:
      - port:
          number: 443
        tls:
          mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
          sni: <my.hostname>
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-nginx-through-egress-gateway
  namespace: tools-istio
spec:
  hosts:
  - <my.hostname>
  gateways:
  - istio-egressgateway
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        subset: nginx
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: <my.hostname>
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: originate-mtls-for-nginx
  namespace: tools-istio
spec:
  host: <my.hostname>
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 443
      tls:
        mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
        sni: <my.hostname>
        # I've also tried with
        # mode: MUTUAL
        # clientCertificate: /etc/nginx-external-tls/tls.crt
        # privateKey: /etc/nginx-external-tls/tls.key
        # caCertificates: /etc/nginx-external-tls/ca.crt
```

When making a query to the external service via `curl` we should get the HTML web code, but instead, it tries to execute the query with HTTP, not HTTPS, **why ??**. `istio-proxy` from debugger pod should translate HTTP into HTTPS using Citadel certificates

```
 $ kubectl -n tools-istio exec -it debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9 -c debugger -- curl http://<my.hostname> -v
*   Trying <my.hostname>:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <my.hostname> (<private_ip_address>) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: <my.hostname>
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 91
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Wed, 08 Jan 2020 09:29:09 GMT
< server: envoy
<
* Connection #0 to host <my.hostname> intact
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
```

When verifying `proxy-status` I get the following

```
$ istioctl proxy-status
NAME                                                   CDS                            LDS        EDS               RDS          PILOT                            VERSION
debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9.tools-istio                  STALE (Never Acknowledged)     SYNCED     SYNCED (51%)      SYNCED       istio-pilot-5f45f6768c-fmvr7     1.2.10
istio-egressgateway-5ff889c5fd-jtz55.istio-system      SYNCED                         SYNCED     SYNCED (100%)     SYNCED       istio-pilot-5f45f6768c-fmvr7     1.2.10
istio-ingressgateway-779cfdd879-bb7w7.istio-system     STALE (Never Acknowledged)     SYNCED     SYNCED (96%)      NOT SENT     istio-pilot-5f45f6768c-fmvr7     1.2.10
```

Which according with official [`istio` docs](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/) can mean, either a missconfiguration in `.yaml`, either an `istio` bug

When checking endpoint everything looks fine

```
$ istioctl proxy-config endpoint debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9.tools-istio | grep <my.hostname>
<private_ip_address>:80         HEALTHY     outbound|80||<my.hostname>
<private_ip_address>:443        HEALTHY     outbound|443||<my.hostname>
```

Othewise debugger pod `istio-proxy` logs show the errors below. But the external certificate is not at pod level, but in a recompiled `istio-egressgateway` (again this is nothing funcy, I've just followed istio docs), so why istio-proxy is looking for the external certificates **??**

```
[2020-01-08 07:56:04.827][17][debug][init] [external/envoy/source/common/init/watcher_impl.cc:27] init manager Cluster outbound|443||afv.test.recouv destroyed
[2020-01-08 07:56:04.827][17][warning][config] [external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_subscription_impl.cc:73] gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Cluster rejected: Error adding/updating cluster(s) outbound|443||<my.hostname>: Invalid path: /etc/nginx-external-tls/tls.crt
```

Pilot logs shows the same, `istio-proxy` container of debugger pod keep looking for external service CA certificate, but this certs are in `egressgateway`

```
$ kubectl -n istio-system logs istio-pilot-5f45f6768c-fmvr7 -c discovery | grep <my.hostname>

2020-01-08T08:48:54.536073Z     warn    ads     ADS:CDS: ACK ERROR 127.0.0.1:60012 sidecar~10.27.187.219~debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9.tools-istio~tools-istio.svc.cluster.local-15433 (debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9.tools-istio) version_info:"2020-01-08T07:50:00Z/110" node:<id:"sidecar~10.27.187.219~debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9.tools-istio~tools-istio.svc.cluster.local" cluster:"debugger.tools-istio" metadata:<fields:<key:"CONFIG_NAMESPACE" value:<string_value:"tools-istio" > > fields:<key:"INCLUDE_INBOUND_PORTS" value:<string_value:"8080" > > fields:<key:"INTERCEPTION_MODE" value:<string_value:"REDIRECT" > > fields:<key:"ISTIO_META_INSTANCE_IPS" value:<string_value:"10.27.187.219,10.27.187.219,fe80::a07f:d0ff:feec:5e71" > > fields:<key:"ISTIO_PROXY_SHA" value:<string_value:"istio-proxy:f9c0feb10cc42277e97dd080a2e045f62d1739a9" > > fields:<key:"ISTIO_PROXY_VERSION" value:<string_value:"1.1.3" > > fields:<key:"ISTIO_VERSION" value:<string_value:"1.2.10" > > fields:<key:"POD_NAME" value:<string_value:"debugger-5844b6d674-4fvt9" > > fields:<key:"app" value:<string_value:"debugger" > > fields:<key:"istio" value:<string_value:"sidecar" > > fields:<key:"pod-template-hash" value:<string_value:"5844b6d674" > > fields:<key:"prometheus.io/path" value:<string_value:"/metrics" > > fields:<key:"prometheus.io/port" value:<string_value:"8080" > > fields:<key:"prometheus.io/scrape" value:<string_value:"true" > > fields:<key:"sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers" value:<string_value:"true" > > > locality:<> build_version:"f9c0feb10cc42277e97dd080a2e045f62d1739a9/1.11.0-dev/Modified/RELEASE/BoringSSL" > type_url:"type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Cluster" response_nonce:"59a1bb9a-aca6-47c0-b718-a86d7e392db0" error_detail:<code:13 message:"Error adding/updating cluster(s) outbound|443||afv.test.recouv: Invalid path: /etc/nginx-external-tls/tls.crt" >
  message: "Error adding/updating cluster(s) outbound|443||<my.hostname>: Invalid path: /etc/nginx-external-tls/tls.crt"
```

In `istio-egressgateway` everything seams to be OK

```
$ kubectl -n istio-system logs istio-egressgateway-5ff889c5fd-jtz55
[2020-01-08 08:59:53.737][24][debug][upstream] [external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:527] updating TLS cluster outbound_.80_._.<my.hostname>
[2020-01-08 08:59:53.737][24][debug][upstream] [external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:975] membership update for TLS cluster outbound_.80_._.<my.hostname> added 1 removed 0
[2020-01-08 08:59:53.737][24][debug][upstream] [external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:527] updating TLS cluster outbound_.443_._.<my.hostname>
[2020-01-08 08:59:53.737][24][debug][upstream] [external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:975] membership update for TLS cluster outbound_.443_._.<my.hostname> added 1 removed 0
```

And of course, certificates are present as they should in `istio-egressgateway`. I've used a cert-manager cluster issuer to deliver a certificate for the external service, like that the AC and it's secrets are already on the cluster

```
# External AC
$ kubectl -n istio-system exec -it istio-egressgateway-5ff889c5fd-jtz55 -- ls /etc/cluster-issuer-tls
tls.crt  tls.key

# Client
$ kubectl -n istio-system exec -it istio-egressgateway-5ff889c5fd-jtz55 -- ls /etc/nginx-external-tls
ca.crt  tls.crt  tls.key
```

**Has anyone any clue about what I'm missing ?? Is this a missconfiguration or a bug ??**

Any help will be really appreciated, I've been stucked with this since before Christmas holidays

Cheers

Comment: First of let me start with that istio version `1.2` has been tested with these Kubernetes releases: 1.12, 1.13, 1.14. https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/setup/kubernetes/

Comment: The first link You added is from istio version `1.2`. Then later from `1.4` (current). Make sure those operations were available in version `1.2`. I'm going  to try to reproduce this on my cluster. If You could share Your cluster environment/infrastructure information this could be very helpful.

Comment: Thank's for your comments @PiotrMalec ! I know that istio 1.2 has been tested just with that versions of, but unhappily (for me) I don't have the power to decide which version of Kubernetes or Istio install and/or use (even if I've tried to explain the client the possible consequences). I'm trying to do my best with what it has been given to me

Comment: Concerning the difference in versions of linked docs, it is normal, the first one makes reference to version 1.2 of istio, the one I'm currently using, the second one is just the one on which I've found an explanation for statuses meaning (so not very important, I think)

Comment: My cluster is an **on premise** K8s with 1 master, 2 nodes. Master and nodes are VMs under ESX. The OS is a **Centos 7 with a  5.2.10-1.el7 kernel** (from ElRepo). `kubectl` and `istio` versions are already detailed in the question. I have MTLs setup in the namespace attacking the external service. If you need any information more, please don't hesitate to ask for it. ***Thank you very much to try to reply the problem in your env.***

Comment: Can you check if in Your service deployment has port name in its manifest? Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560394/how-to-terminate-ssl-at-ingress-gateway-in-istio/59578064#59578064)? (the service with app that is in injected pod).

Comment: I'm not using a Service Deployment because I'm attacking an NGINX running on a VM. I'm trying to adapt the provided example from istio docs, which configure an NGINX inside a K8s cluster, but external to mesh network, to a real life situation. If you want to know if the source service (from which I'm attacking the external NGINX) has a named port in it's `Service` and `Deployment` declaration, the answer is YES

Comment: I think there could be something miss-configured with Your istio/kubernetes cluster. Check if without any deployments and istio in its base configuration you still get `Stale (Never Acknowledged)` under `CDS` for `istio.ingressgateway-<podnumber>.istio-system` when calling `istioctl proxy-status`.

Comment: I don't think so, because, before trying to implement MTLs via `istio-egressgateway` for external traffic, I've tested [TLS origination for egress traffic](https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/#tls-origination-for-egress-traffic) without the `egressgateway`, and it works as it should, there is not `Stale` status on CDS. But I'm going to try to make everything again and I'll keep you updated. Thanks anyway @PiotrMalec

Comment: OK my bad, I've found the error, there was no problem with K8s/istio cluster configuration, **I was missing create and mount secrets in the source pod**. I thought it would take the ones from Citadel directly. But actually, if I create a new secret with `cert-manager` for the internal service and reconfigure egressgateway with it. This allows to establish MTLs connection to an external service and has the advantage of been able to recognize the source in the server (with citadel certificates we have just the IP of the pod source, but no name, because CN in certificate is empty)