# Why does using TLS lead to an upstream error when using istio in a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio, error-logging

I am trying to deploy a Service in a Kubernetes Cluster. Everything works fine as long as I do not use TLS.

My Setup is like this:
Azure Kubernetes Cluster with Version 1.15.7
Istio 1.4.2

What I did so far is. Creating the Cluster and Installing Istio with the following Command:

```
istioctl manifest apply --set values.grafana.enabled=true \--set values.tracing.enabled=true \
--set values.tracing.provider=jaeger \
--set values.global.mtls.enabled=false \
--set values.global.imagePullPolicy=Always \
--set values.kiali.enabled=true \
--set "values.kiali.dashboard.jaegerURL=http://jaeger-query:16686" \
--set "values.kiali.dashboard.grafanaURL=http://grafana:3000"
```

Everything starts up and all pods are running.
Then I create a Gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ddhub-ingressgateway
  namespace: config
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*.example.de"
    #  tls:
    #    httpsRedirect: true # sends 301 redirect for http requests
    - port:
        number: 443
        name: https
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        mode: SIMPLE
        serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
        privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      hosts:
        - "*.example.de"
    - port:
        number: 31400
        name: tcp
        protocol: TCP
      hosts:
        - "*.example.de"
```

I then import my custom certificates which I assume also work since they are mounted correctly and when accessing my service over the browser I can see the secured connection properties with all values.

This is my deployed service:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hellohub-frontend
  labels:
    app: hellohub-frontend
  namespace: dev
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hellohub-frontend
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hellohub-frontend
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hellohub-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ddhubregistry.azurecr.io/hellohub-frontend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: hellohub-frontend
          volumeMounts:
          - name: azure
            mountPath: /cloudshare
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: azure
        azureFile:
          secretName: cloudshare-dev
          shareName: ddhub-share-dev
          readOnly: true
```

and the Virtual Service:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hellohub-frontend
  namespace: dev
spec:
  hosts:
    - "dev-hellohub.example.de"
  gateways:
    - config/ddhub-ingressgateway
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: hellohub-frontend.dev.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 8080
```

When I access the service with http. The page of my service shows up. When using https I always get "upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination".

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong? What is the difference that makes Kubernetes not finding my service. I understand that my config terminates TLS at the gateway and the communication inside the cluster is the same but this seems not to be the case.

Another question is how to enable debug logs for the Sidecars. I could not find a working way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @Quorgel, could You check if adding name to your service,like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59578064/11977760), helps?

Comment: Yes that's it! Thank you now it works. As always it's the details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using istioctl to change log level of istio-proxy.

```
istioctl proxy-config log <pod-name[.namespace]> --level all:warning,http:debug,redis:debug
```

Comment: Thanks now I can play around with the loglevels.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the gateway tried to access your upstream in mtls mode through the envoy proxy, but no envoy proxy found in your container "hellohub-frontend", Have you enabled the istio-injection for your namespace "dev" or the pod, and also defined the mtls-policy?

```
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: "default"
spec:
  peers:
  - mtls:
      mode: STRICT
```

Comment: I used `labels:
    istio-injection: enabled`The policy I did not define but I tried it but it makes no difference

Comment: Did you get any insights from the logs? Has the problem been solved?

Comment: I did not get valuable information from the logs however they where showing debug infos and that was also something that never really worked before. The problem was the missing name in my Service config as jt97 suggested in the comment above.